# Generate a custom pdf with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I'm building an app with Flutter, at some point I have to generate a custom pdf after I fill some forms inside the app. The generated PDF should resemble the image bellow. How can I make such a thing? and how should I approach this?

[image]

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have checked this package but it doesn't support Web unfortunately

Comment: Thank you @KJ for this info, I wasn't aware of this FDF thing, I'll be looking more into it. If you have some links to share I'd appreciate it. But still I don't know how I'm gonna implement this in/with Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Custom XFAs  like the one shown are specific to Adobe Live Cycle products and are not designed to be outside fully Adobe licensed applications. So as advised by Adobe some time ago, they are depreciated non ISO standard, and to be replaced by Open Licensed PDFs (ISO standard) Acroform replacements. As such this file type is now defunct, and a newer copy is to be distributed.

[image: enter image 1description here]

The idea of these forms is the field user adds their field details in a mobile reader. However the Template can be pre-populated by office staff importing the PDF by using an FDF that has the common data. Here I have only filled the first 2 dummy entries.

[image]
[image]
Thus the field operative will already have the prior known data provided and only need to fill in a few site specific ones.

[image]

So it is unlikely there are lighterweight editors able to build such files. They are best built in a Workstation Graphics User Interface. and the Flutter user only needs to be able to type field entries, in a suitable Acroforms reader Like MS Edge.

[image]